# How to split a list of arrays in decreasing order using split function in python?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, split

I am trying to take array input from user and split arrays in sub-arrays with 3 elements on each. If no. of elements in array is not evenly divisible by 3, I want to increase the size of smaller arrays by 1 from the first sub array.

I tried using split function but that gives me sub arrays in increasing order. I want it in decreasing order.

```py
import numpy as np
def array_list(x):

  original_list = []
  for i in range (0,x):
    abc = input("Enter element: ")
    original_list.append(abc)
  original_list.sort()
  return(original_list)

x = int(input("Enter no. of elements: "))
Input = array_list(x)
print("Input = ",Input)
print("Output = ",np.split(Input,[3]))
```

My code executes like this::

```
Input =  ['11', '13', '15', '23', '34', '7', '77']  
Output =  [array(['11','13','15']),array(['23','34','7','77']]
```

I expect  my output as:

```
Input =  ['11', '13', '15', '23', '34', '7', '77']    
Output = [array(['11','13','15',23], array(['34','7', '77']
```

Also I need help in sorting

Comment: You may have to calculate the splits yourself, and use `np.array_split`.

Comment: can you help me on that please?

Comment: You used `np.splilt(x,[3])`; `np.array_split(x, 2)` does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is you need to convert the number `abc` to `int` (as you did for `x`) to sort the number. To split the array as you want, you can reverse the array before splitting.

```py
import numpy as np


def array_list(x):
    original_list = []
    for i in range(0, x):
        abc = int(input("Enter element: "))
        original_list.append(abc)
    original_list.sort(reverse=True)
    return original_list


x = int(input("Enter no. of elements: "))
Input = array_list(x)
print("Input = ", Input)
Output = np.array_split(Input, int(x/3)) if x >= 3 else Input
print("Output = ", Output)
```

```
# test 1
Enter no. of elements: 7
Input =  [77, 34, 23, 15, 13, 11, 7]
Output =  [array([77, 34, 23, 15]), array([13, 11,  7])]

# test 2
Enter no. of elements: 8
Input =  [77, 45, 34, 23, 15, 13, 11, 7]
Output =  [array([77, 45, 34, 23]), array([15, 13, 11,  7])]

# test 3
Enter no. of elements: 9
Input =  [99, 77, 45, 34, 23, 15, 13, 11, 7]
Output =  [array([99, 77, 45]), array([34, 23, 15]), array([13, 11,  7])]
```

Comment: I want last Output as Output = [array([77, 34, 23,15]), array([13, 11,  7])]

Comment: just modified my answer

Comment: I am getting error on your code. It says     Output = [l[::-1] for l in Input][::-1]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I think it run well on the input array given in the question. modified again for larger x

Comment: Thank you Matt. This helped me solve the issue for both sorting and decreasing order of splitting arrays. I appreciate your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [16]: x = np.array(['11', '13', '15', '23', '34', '7', '77'])                
In [17]: np.array_split(x,[4,3])                                                
Out[17]: 
[array(['11', '13', '15', '23'], dtype='<U2'),
 array([], dtype='<U2'),
 array(['23', '34', '7', '77'], dtype='<U2')]
```

A tentative way of calculating the split:

```
In [25]: s = x.shape[0]                                                         
In [26]: cnt = s//3                                                             
In [27]: extra = s%3                                                            
In [28]: alist = [3+1]*extra + [3]*(cnt-extra)                                  
In [29]: alist                                                                  
Out[29]: [4, 3]
```

But wait, `array_split` does it this way already:

```
In [33]: np.array_split(x,2)                                                    
Out[33]: 
[array(['11', '13', '15', '23'], dtype='<U2'),
 array(['34', '7', '77'], dtype='<U2')]
```

[How does the numpy function `array_split` work mathematically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58756377/901925)