# Are chunks returned by 'np.array_split()' ordered by descending sizes?

Tags: python, numpy

In `numpy.array_split` using an integer, when the number of parts isn't a divisor of the size on the axis considered, some parts may be smaller or larger, e.g.

```
import numpy as np
[chunk.shape[0] for chunk in np.array_split(np.arange(12), 5)]
```

returns chunk sizes: `[3, 3, 2, 2, 2]`

While [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy.array_split) doesn't mention it, it seems chunks with the smallest sizes are at the end of the list. And trying for a sample confirms this is true for arrays up to 200 elements, whatever the number of chunks required.

```
import numpy as np    
not_ordered = 0
for sample_size in np.arange(2,200):
    a = np.arange(sample_size)
    for n in np.arange(2,sample_size//2):
        chunks = np.array_split(a,n)
        sizes = [chunk.shape[0] for chunk in chunks]
        for i in np.arange(1, len(sizes)):
            if sizes[i] > sizes[i-1]:
                not_ordered += 1
                break
print (f'Not ordered: {not_ordered}')
```

Is the descending order guaranteed by the algorithm behind the function? or is this something not to count on when using the result returned?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58756377/how-does-the-numpy-function-array-split-work-mathematically

Comment: @marcdtheking, I read this question (and offered the bounty), it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

[numpy.array_split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy.array_split) docs says

> For an array of length l that should be split into n sections, it
> returns l % n sub-arrays of size l//n + 1 and the rest of size l//n.

As `l` and `n` are fixed in each run, we can conclude that for every element in returned array next one will be no longer than current.

Edit: when in doubt, as this is `python`, we can [read the code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.0/numpy/lib/shape_base.py#L739-L792). As you are interesting in case where `indices_or_sections` is integer relevant piece is:

```
Nsections = int(indices_or_sections)
if Nsections <= 0:
    raise ValueError('number sections must be larger than 0.')
Neach_section, extras = divmod(Ntotal, Nsections)
section_sizes = ([0] +
                 extras * [Neach_section+1] +
                 (Nsections-extras) * [Neach_section])
div_points = _nx.array(section_sizes, dtype=_nx.intp).cumsum()
```

where `Ntotal` is number of elements in your input array. As you can see there are `Neach_section+1`s followed by `Neach_sections`s.

Comment: Do you infer that from "*and the rest*" meaning *the rest which comes at the end of the list?*

Comment: @mins Yes, this is how I understand this.

Answer (score 1):

No they are not sorted during the split so the groups may not be in order. I am using the qcut function to guarantee ranked groups. I tried using np.array_split however the data was not sorted in the deciles which causes issue for my project. Below is a code example of how I got ranked groups (deciles in this case).

`df['Decile'] = pd.qcut(dev2['variable_name'], 10, labels=False)`